# attack of the b team server isn't working well please help

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

My Attack of the B Team server suddenly shut down. When it is starting it crashes.

This is the crash report:

```
Encountered an unexpected exception IllegalArgumentException
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Too big view radius!
    at net.minecraft.server.management.PlayerManager.<init>   (SourceFile:166)
    at net.minecraft.world.WorldServer.<init>(WorldServer.java:113)
    at  net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.func_71247_a(MinecraftServer.java:24 6)
    at net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer.func_71197_b(DedicatedSe rver.java:187)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:445)
    at net.minecraft.server.ThreadMinecraftServer.run(SourceFile:583)
2014-06-03 15:43:57 [SEVERE] [Minecraft-Server] This crash report has   been saved to:   /Users/rodrigobracamonte/Desktop/BTeam_Server_v1.0.10b/./crash- reports/crash-2014-06-03_15.43.57-server.txt
2014-06-03 15:44:03 [INFO] [ForgeModLoader] [BiomesOPlenty] Version check failed
```

What can I do to fix this? 3 days ago it worked perfectly well.

Comment: I think it says the error right at, `Too big view radius!`. Not sure what that means though...

Comment: Are you sure that you're including the whole error report? After looking through some error reports, there should be a very short description at the top of the report that states the issue.

Comment: I've changed my mind and flagged this for closure. An off-topic question is still off-topic even if one could copy-paste the exact same answer to a hypothetical on-topic question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because technical support for modded minecraft is considered off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

As DatEpicCoderGuyWhoPrograms points out, the error here is

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Too big view radius!
```

You will need to locate your `server.properties` file. On Unix, this file is generated in the working directory, according to the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Server.properties#File_Location). Just search for it if you can't find it in the usual suspect folders (like the server folder, or your user folder).

Open the file with a text editor, and change the entry for `view-distance` to a value between 3 and 15. 10 is recommended, high view distances are quite demanding on your system.